# How to include relayState parameter in SAML single Logout request using Spring SAML extension

Tags: java, spring-saml, pingfederate

I am using **Spring SAML extension** and **PingFederate** as a IDP server. Now when I am initiating **global logou**t from SP (service provider) then it only invalidate the SP session not IDP server session. Means even after global logout when I again try to login (using SP initiated)then it allow to login directly without asking user login credentials.

I noticed that in SAML single logout request **relayState** parameter is missing, though it is there in other SP application that is working fine (demo SP application provided by PingFederate). I tried to add relayState property in securityContext.xml file (refer below snippet) but still relayState is not a part of logout request parameter.

```
<bean id="samlEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLEntryPoint">
    <property name="defaultProfileOptions">
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileOptions">
            <property name="relayState" value="http://192.168.1.73:8080/adeptia"/>
            <property name="includeScoping" value="true"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Please let me know what is the use of relayState parameter and what's the possible value and how to include it in SAML logout request.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to pass relay state by extending `SingleLogoutProfileImpl` - method `sendLogoutRequest`. You can call `context.setRelayState()` to get the value in, and then super to do the rest of the logic.

During response phase the relay value will be available in the `processLogoutResponse`, again in the context object.

There's no explicit feature for sending of the relay during Single Logout in Spring SAML.